# Dynamically auto populating a limit_choices_to field upon change of a foreignkey

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, models

This might be a little far fetched, but I want to give it a try anyway.

I want to auto populate a m2m field when the user selects a foreignkey from the same model.

For example:

```
venue = models.ForeignKey(Instance)
kill = models.ManyToManyField(Boss)
```

Now, Boss has a relation to Instance already in Instance.instance what I want is when someone selects the venue say object #1 then the m2m field will automagically update to only boss objects from that instance.

I don't even know where to start with this, google has not really helped at all. Maybe the way I'm searching for it is wrong.

Comment: If you mean that you want to update a form's choices, Django does not do this out of the box - it requires Javascript to dynamically update the HTML. Django smart selects is a third-party package that I've often seen recommended for this purpose: https://github.com/digi604/django-smart-selects

Comment: Does django-smart-selects cater for manytomanyfield? as far as I can see in the docs, it doesn't.

Comment: Hmm, looks like it doesn't. So you'll need either a different package (I don't know of one offhand) or custom javascript.

Comment: I think it's going to turn out to be more work than it's worth.